# Flyout Menu Click Issue

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using flyout menu in my app. I followed https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu to make it working. It works. Although I have a small issue. When the screen is showing ContentLayout, when clicks over it underlying menu redirects to the activity, which is specified in the particular menu item.

How can i make the menu work only when it is on top?

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
            FindViewById (Resource.Id.rcd).Clickable = false;
            FindViewById (Resource.Id.rcd).Focusable = false;
            FindViewById (Resource.Id.rcd).Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Seems like a very dirty solution. Instead of using FlyOutMenu I would consider using a standardized component, like DrawerLayout from Android Support v4. This doesn't have that kind of issues.

Comment: @Cheesebaron May i ask for decent solution? because i couldn't find any.